# How to identify where a particular block come from?

Tags: 6, nodes, blocks

I have to modify a block that appears on the home page of the website, that I did not make myself. The block appears in `admin/build/block` with the title "Block Title (nodeblock)", so I assume that this has  been created by the nodeblock module, but I can't find where I can edit this content.

Can someone help me to find the right administration menu to view and modify this nodeblock content ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

It appears from a quick look at the module source that `nodeblock` uses the node's nid as the block delta.

So, from `admin/build/block` if you click on the `configure` link on the block in question, it should take you to something along the lines of `admin/build/block/configure/nodeblock/###`.  That trailing `###` is the nid of the node in the block.  So then off you go to `node/###/edit`.

OTHERWISE:

If this is just a one-off thing, a quick look at the default `node-nodeblock-default.tpl.php` template for creating these blocks shows...

```
<div id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="node<?php if ($sticky) { print ' sticky'; } ?><?php if (!$status) { print ' node-unpublished'; } ?> clear-block">
```

...so I would just surf over to your home page, and then take a peek at the source generated in your browser, and there it should show a `<div>` wrapping this block with an `id` of `node-###`.

Then, going to `node/###/edit` should take you on your way.

Comment: Great ! Both methods are OK, thanks. We could probably suggest to nodeblock module developers to add a "Edit node" menu somewhere ...

Comment: Note that looking at div IDs and classes isn't always going to work because it is possible your block templates do not print that stuff out. It is very often a good solution though.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for Drupal 6 would probably be to use the [Contextual links](https://drupal.org/project/contextual) module.

> Hover over nodes, blocks, and views blocks to expose styled
>   edit/configure/delete tabs.

It's a backport of the same functionality that is in D7 core, but for Drupal 6.

Just hover over the block on the front page, and hit edit to edit that particular block.